# Cannot upload apk to GooglePlay - Assignment will fail, as these versions do not exist

Tags: android, jenkins, google-play-console

I'm having a signed apk file that I want to upload via Jenkins Android-Plugin to Google Play.
I have a manually added version in Google Play console that is in Production (version code 4) and one in open testing (version code 96) which I uploaded via Jenkins long time ago.
During those two attempts I changed a lot in Jenkins, so that now there's version code 48.

The upload fails with the following message:

```
Gestartet durch Benutzer Jenkins Build
Running as SYSTEM
Baue auf Master in Arbeitsbereich /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/xxx/xxx Jobs/Publish to Google
1 Artefakt aus "xxx » xxx Jobs » Get Artifact" Buildnummer 62 kopiert
Found APK file with version code 48: xxx-1.0.48-release.apk
Authenticating to Google Play API...
- Credential:     xxx
- Application ID: xxx
Assignment will fail, as these versions do not exist on Google Play: 48
ERROR: Assignment failed
Sending e-mails to: xxx
Finished: FAILURE
```

The Jenkins Plugin is configured as reading the version from the apk file.

Jenkins itself set's the version code in the app specific build.gradle and running gradle.

```
vStringOld=$(grep 'versionCode ' app/build.gradle | xargs)
vStringNew="versionCode ${BUILD_NUMBER}"
sed -i "s/$vStringOld/$vStringNew/1" app/build.gradle
```

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxx"
        minSdk 26
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 48
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        archivesBaseName="xxx-$versionName.$versionCode"
    }
```

```
./gradlew clean
./gradlew assemble
```

During both uploads (96 with Jenkins) and now I added "archivesBaseName="xxx-$versionName.$versionCode"" to app specific build.gradle.

I already tried to change the upload scope (production, beta, ...) and also tried changing the app version manually to 4 (as there is already that version) in production.
Also I tried changing the version from 4 to 48 in Google Play.